# How can I use other materials to upgrade gear in Marvel Future Fight?

Tags: marvel-future-fight

I'm playing [Marvel Future Fight](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/marvel-heroes-united/id955705796) for **iOS** and I am with my heroes at level 18. I have many other materials to perform the **upgrade gear** but none of them appears in the boxes.

[image: Inventory screen]

eg: I have 6 **High Strength Fiber**, which says: "The basic materials to upgrade Combat type Hero Gear".

But all these other materials are not available for me to do this upgrade, even though I try to upgrade **Captain America**, a **Combat Hero**.

[image: Upgrade Gear screen]

### My question

Is there any level limitation or anything else that would prevent me from using these materials to upgrade? I can't find this answer anywhere, even in the game manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**These upgrade equipment are required for higher level Gear upgrades.**

[image]

In the above image, you can see the new item next to the upgrade kit box.

Then, here you can see the Norn stone in the mastery option.
[image]

Comment: That's it! Other materials are available only from the level +5 of each Gear. This information does not really exist anywhere in the game or manual. Thanks!

Comment: Most welcome.... Yeah this game is pretty vague when it comes to this... I spent a day or two figuring out the heads and tails of it

Comment: You can find where to get various required components by clicking on the component on the character screen.

Comment: @FredMorrisNapier - right you are... but until you reach that upgrade level for that gear, it doesn't show where you would be using those special materials...

Answer (score -1):

Upgrading equipment past +4 requires other materials besides upgrade gear.